# ODE - getting reciprocal of correct answer

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the first order differential equation
$$(1+x^2)\frac{dy}{dx}=x(1-y^2), \quad y(0)=2.$$

I've tried to solve this by separating variables, and I get
$$y=\frac{3(1+x^2)-1}{3(1+x^2)+1}.$$

However, Wolfram Alpha gives the reciprocal of this.

---

During my solution, I ended up with
\begin{equation}\log|1+y|-\log|1-y|=\log|3(1+x^2)|,\end{equation}
which I simplified to
$$\log\left|\frac{1+y}{1-y}\right|=\log |3(1+x^2)|,$$
and subsequently got my answer.

**However,** if I had simplified this to
$$\log\left|\frac{1+y}{y-1}\right|=\log |3(1+x^2)|,$$
I get the same answer as WA.

---

What's going on here? What's wrong with my initial approach?

---

**EDIT**

After arriving at
$$\log\left|\frac{1+y}{1-y}\right|=\log |3(1+x^2)|,$$
I wrote
$$e^{\log\left|\frac{1+y}{1-y}\right|}=e^{\log |3(1+x^2)|},$$
and then
$$\frac{1+y}{1-y}=3(1+x^2).$$

Perhaps this is where the issue arises?

Comment: where is the factor of $3$ from in your initial approach?

Comment: @mrsamy It appears from applying the condition $y(0)=2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is often helpful to determine the constants only after getting rid of the absolute value. That is, first find
$$
\frac{1+y}{1-y}=C(1+x^2), ~~C\in\Bbb R\cup\{\infty\}
$$
then use the initial condition to find the constant with the correct sign, $C=-3$. Continue transforming as you did to find the reciprocal of your first solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can check that your answer does not satisfy the initial condition $y(0)=2$, but the reciprocal of your answer does.

Your intermediate steps look correct to me. It is a matter of how you "subsequently got your answer".

---

Notes.

$$
\log\left|\frac{1+y}{1-y}\right|=\log |3(1+x^2)|=\log(3(1+x^2))$$
implies that
$$
\left|\frac{1+y}{1-y}\right|=3(1+x^2)
$$
which implies
$$
\frac{1+y}{1-y}=3(1+x^2),\quad \color{red}{(1+y)(1-y)>0}\tag{1}
$$
**or**
$$
\frac{1+y}{y-1}=3(1+x^2),\quad \color{red}{(1+y)(1-y)<0}\tag{2}
$$

When you get rid of the absolute value on the left, you need to consider the sign.

Comment: I've made an edit.

Comment: Thank you—your answer is useful. How would I have known to go for the second of your two possibilities?

Comment: @MHW: simply solve for $y$ from identities in both (1) and (2) to see if the corresponding inequalities are satisfied.